# I call ajax only once but ajax is called many times

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am trying to write some code to make a request when I click a button. When I click my button, multiple requests are being made, and I can't figure out why this is happening.

Here is the code of the button in the blade file:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @if(!empty($textLesson))

    @php
    $text_id=$textLesson->id;
    $webinar_id=$webinar->id;
    $lessonAudio = App\Models\AudioAttachment::where('text_lesson_id',$text_id)->get();
    @endphp

    <div id="btnDiv">
        <x-panel.attach-audio-component :textid="$text_id" :webinarid="$webinar_id" :textLesson="$textLesson"
            :userLanguages="$userLanguages" />
    </div>
    @if(!empty($lessonAudio) and !$lessonAudio->isEmpty())

    <div id="audioListings">

      </div>
```

Here is the script where ajax is called:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('body').on('click', '#addAudio', function (e) {
            const $this = $(this);
            $textid = document.getElementById("addAudio").getAttribute("data-text-id");
            $webinarid = $this.attr('data-webinar-id');
            //alert($textid);
            e.preventDefault();
            let add_audio_modal = '<form id="addAudioFiles" method="post" action="/panel/text-lesson/saveaudio"  enctype= "multipart/form-data">';
            add_audio_modal += '@csrf';
            add_audio_modal += $('#audioFilesModal').html();
            add_audio_modal += '</div>';

            Swal.fire({
                html: add_audio_modal,
                showCancelButton: false,
                showConfirmButton: false,
                customClass: {
                    content: 'p-0 text-left',
                },
                width: '48rem',
            });
        });

        $('body').on('click', '#saveaudios', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            const $this = $(this);
            let form = $('#addAudioFiles');

            let formData = new FormData(form[0]);
            formData.append('webinar_id', $webinarid);
            formData.append('text_id', $textid);
            let action = form.attr('action');

            $this.addClass('loadingbar gray').prop('disabled', true);
            form.find('input').removeClass('is-invalid');
            form.find('textarea').removeClass('is-invalid');

            $.ajax({
                url: action,
                type: 'POST',
                data: formData, // use the FormData object as the data to be submitted
                processData: false, // prevent jQuery from processing the data
                contentType: false, // let the browser set the content type automatically
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result && result.code === 200) {

                       // do with result

                      
                    
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    // error handling code here
                  
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

i dont know why multiple requests are being made. please any one can help

Comment: There's a *massive* amount of code here. Please reduce it to a [mcve]. Preferably using the [live demo](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) feature of the question editor.

Comment: Can't tell what result your blade will be producing, especially regarding what IDs the elements will have. So is this button you are generating there `#addAudio`, or `#saveaudios`? And do you have this button on your page once, or are you rendering multiple of them? If the latter, you would of course need to see to it that you are not duplicating IDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your `$('body').on('click', '#saveaudios', function (e) {});` register click events multiple times. This might because of your script is loaded multiple times, event propagation or so on. So, you need to remove the previous event with [`off()`](https://api.jquery.com/off/) event handler. So, your new code will looks as follows:

```
$('body').off('click', '#saveaudios').on('click', '#saveaudios', function(e) {
    // your ajax logic
});
```